New message indicator badge implementation in Android XML
I have an application which acts nearly as a messaging service, constantly checking for some king of new messages. Such apps as WhatsApp, Viber, Telegram etc. have those new message circular indicator badges.

Personally, I like Telegram implementation, because of its dynamic size changing - when there are few digits inside the badge, indicator is round, when the number is growing the view is widening to rounded corner rectangle.

Trying to implement such feature in my XML layout I tried following:
TextView with Shape as background
Implemented something like this:
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/newMessagesNumber"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
 android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimaryVariant"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:includeFontPadding="false"
 android:paddingStart="7dp"
 android:paddingTop="3dp"
 android:paddingEnd="7dp"
 android:paddingBottom="3dp"
 android:textColor="?attr/colorOnPrimary"
 tools:text="100" />

And @drawable/rounded_corner:
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="16dp" />
</shape>

Result is:

Pros:

Simple
Looks good

Cons:

Heavily depending on paddings - can backfire on some screens.
On small numbers it's nearly a circle - again, all because of paddings.




Custom View
class CircularTextView
    (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) :
    AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val circlePaint = Paint()
    private var isDrawingCircle = false
    private var roundRadius = 40f
    init {
        circlePaint.setColor(getThemeColorRes(R.attr.colorPrimaryVariant, context))
        circlePaint.flags = Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val h = height.toFloat()
        val w = width.toFloat()
        val centerX = w / 2
        val centerY = h / 2
        val radius = (h/2).toInt()

           if (isDrawingCircle)
               canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius.toFloat(), circlePaint)
           else
               canvas.drawRoundRect(0f, 0f, w, h, roundRadius, roundRadius, circlePaint)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }


    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        isDrawingCircle = w <= h
    }


    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        // +10 imitates padding
        // can remove it here and add paddings in XML
        minWidth = measuredHeight + 10
        minimumWidth = measuredHeight + 10
        minHeight = measuredHeight + 10
        minimumHeight = measuredHeight + 10
    }


}


Pros:

Looks good

Cons:

Heavily depending on paddings - can backfire on some screens.
On big numbers you should adjust paddings - corners are overlapping with letters.
Also on big numbers backgorund rounder rectangle gets cut off in the bottom or sometimes in the top.


There is also another approach from StackOverflow - Custom View based on ConstraintLayout that generates a bitmap - looks like an overcomplicated one.

BadgeDrawable

Pros:

Looks perfect

Cons:

Does not support XML, only accessed programmatically.
Mostly used as an add-on to navigation bar, menus, navigation rail, top app bars and tabs. So, not a great fit because I was looking for an independent view.


Rounded corners spans

Pros:

Relatively simple

Cons:

On small numbers it's again nearly a circle.
Does not support XML, only accessed programmatically.

Compose inside XML
Wasn't looking deep into this because it looks like an overhead.


Any ideas on clean implementation of such indicators? Or maybe fixing mentioned approaches to look as in example apps.
